# How to fix this error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >="

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Task2_Create1397_1396
AS
DECLARE @Check INT
DECLARE @Sal INT

--SET @Check = (SELECT COUNT(Title)FROM Buy)
SET @Sal = (
        SELECT YEAR(Tarikh)
        FROM Buy
        )

IF (@Sal = 1398)
    INSERT INTO Buy
    SELECT Title
        ,Type1
        ,Tedat
        ,DATEADD(DAY, - 2, DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, Tarikh))
        ,Descrip
    FROM Buy

IF (@Sal = 1397)
    INSERT INTO Buy
    SELECT Title
        ,Type1
        ,Tedat
        ,DATEADD(DAY, - 2, DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, Tarikh))
        ,Descrip
    FROM Buy
```

Comment: Removed irrelevant tags: this is pure SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your technical error - you need to change this

```
SET @Sal = (SELECT YEAR(Tarikh) FROM Buy)
```

into

```
SET @Sal = (SELECT Top 1 YEAR(Tarikh) FROM Buy)
```

> You can use here `order by` clause also in the above `select` statement.

Apart from this you need to check why it is returning more than one value in select while assigning this returning value into a variable.

You can restructure your if statement twice into one as shown below.

```
IF (@Sal = 1398)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Buy
    SELECT Title
        ,Type1
        ,Tedat
        ,DATEADD(DAY, - 2, DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, Tarikh))
        ,Descrip
    FROM Buy -- <add where condition here for if block>
END
ELSE IF (@Sal = 1397)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Buy
    SELECT Title
        ,Type1
        ,Tedat
        ,DATEADD(DAY, - 2, DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, Tarikh))
        ,Descrip
    FROM Buy -- <add where condition here for another if block>
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The only place you have a subquery is:

```
SET @Sal = (SELECT YEAR(Tarikh) FROM Buy);
```

This code -- even if you limited it to one row -- makes no sense.  This returns one row for each row in `Buy`.  Which one do you want?  You don't specify *which* year you want, so I suspect you want:

```
SET @Sal = (SELECT MAX(YEAR(Tarikh)) FROM Buy);
```

Next, it is highly unusual to set a parameter named `@SAL` to a "year" value -- that doesn't work in English, although it might work in another language.  I'm just pointing this out.

The next portion of your code is overly complicated and poorly written:

- The two `IF` blocks are the same (well, except for the `THEN` conditions).
- You are using `INSERT` with no column list.  That is barely acceptable in ad-hoc code.  It should not be allowed in permanent code.
- You can actually eliminate the `IF` entirely.

So, I would recommend:

```
INSERT INTO Buy (Title, Type1, Tedat, Tarikh, Descrip)
    SELECT Title, Type1, Tedat, DATEADD(DAY, - 2, DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, Tarikh)),
           Descrip
    FROM Buy
    WHERE @Sal IN (1398, 1397);
```

Your table doesn't appear to have a primary key.  That would also be a problem, and I would suggest that you fix the data model as well.